# svnadmin dump yields error: Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'

Tags: svn

I am creating dump for the 16 repositories in my SVN installation, which is version 1.6.3 on Windows Server 2003.  Dumps were created successfully for 15 of the 16 repos.  However, one yields the message: Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'.  To my knowledge, all repos were created using the same SVN installation.  Why would one fail and the others succeed?  What can I do to create the dump file for the last repo?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

> Why would one fail and the others succeed?

Format 6 means: repository was created (or schema upgaded from 1.6) with SVN 1.8

> What can I do to create the dump file for the last repo?
>   With local access - use 1.8 version of svnadmin, use *any* existing version of svnrdump (if exist) from remote (require 1.8+ version of client)